# Ruby on Rails - When I create a new post, can it create a new individual page for it to be viewed on as well as my index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I currently have a jobs board that I'm making which when you complete the form it displays the job on the index page. I would like to continue doing so but also generate a individual page for the whole post to display on which I can then link from the index page with a link on the job.position string in the index.html.erb - How would I add this function to my existing code?

- I'm new to rails.

My code is as follows:

jobs_controller.erb -

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:position, :company, :salary, :companywebsite, :companytwitter, :contract, :city, :expirydate, :jobtype, :description, :apply, :contactname, :contactemail, :contactphone, ))
     if @job.save
       redirect_to root_path
     else
       render "new"
     end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb -

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <div class="job">
    <h2><%= job.position %></h2>
    <p>Company: <%= job.company %></p>
    <p>Salary: <%= job.salary %></p>
    <p>Contract Type: <%= job.contract %></p>
    <p>City: <%= job.city %></p>
    <p>Expiry date: <%= job.expirydate %></p>
    <p>Job Type: <%= job.jobtype %></p>
  </div>
 <% end %>

<%= paginate @jobs %>
```

new.html.erb -

```
<%= simple_form_for @job, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <h2>Job Position:</h2>
    <%= form.input :position, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Job Position", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :company, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Company name", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :salary, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Salary", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :companywebsite, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Company Website", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :companytwitter, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Twitter Handle e.g @Hatch_Inc", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contract, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contract Type", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :city, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "City", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :expirydate, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Expiry date", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :jobtype, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Job Type", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :description, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Full job description", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :apply, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "How to apply", label: false %>
    <h2>Your Contact Details:</h2>
    <%= form.input :contactname, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Name", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contactemail, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Email", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contactphone, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Telephone", label: false %>
    <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

job.rb -

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :position, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :salary, presence: true
  validates :companywebsite, presence: true
  validates :companytwitter, presence: true
  validates :contract, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :expirydate, presence: true
  validates :jobtype, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :apply, presence: true
  validates :contactname, presence: true
  validates :contactemail, presence: true
  validates :contactphone, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done with the `show` controller action. Rails will automatically generate the routes for you.

Add this to `routes.rb` :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  ...
```

Then in your controller, add the `show` action:

```
def show
  @job= Job.find(params[:id])
end
```

And finally your job position link:

```
<h2><%= link_to job.position, job %></h2
```

Then you can display it however you like in `app/views/jobs/show.html.erb` e.g.,

```
<p>
  <strong>Position:</strong>
  <%= @job.position%>
</p>
```

Comment: that has done it and created a link to the individual page but its giving an error when I click on the link saying 'Template is missing - no template for jobs/show'? which was what I was thinking, how does it know what to display?

Comment: Sorry for the questions but I've created that and put in the same form thats in my index.html.erb and its given me an error of 'NoMethodError in Jobs#show' with regards to '<% @jobs.each do |job| %>'

Comment: Because you aren't passing in `@jobs` to your show method, you're passing `@job`, singular. Then you can display it however you want, e.g.,

`<p>
  <strong>Position:</strong>
  <%= @job.position %>
</p>`

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example of `show.html.erb`. Also, read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). It explains the basics of controllers and views in Rails.

Comment: So this is wrong because? - <% @job.each do |job| %>
            <div class="job">
                <h2><%= job.position %></h2>
                <p>Company: <%= job.company %></p>
                <p>Salary: <%= job.salary %></p>
                <p>Contract Type: <%= job.contract %></p>
                <p>City: <%= job.city %></p>
                <p>Expiry date: <%= job.expirydate %></p>
                <p>Job Type: <%= job.jobtype %></p>
                <p>Full Description:<br><br><%= job.description %></p>
            </div>
        <% end %>

Comment: It's wrong because `@job` is a single object... why are you trying to loop through it?

Comment: Oh so I don't need the @job.each do |job| at the start?

Comment: However, with just the <%= job.position %> is giving me a 'NameError in Jobs#show' error?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can display each field directly with `@job.position`, `@job.company`, etc.

Comment: Read the examples I've given. you need the `@` to access objects you've passed from your controller.

Comment: Oh jesus, realised where I was going wrong, thank you for your patience! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `show` action. It does what you are talking about. First, add this to your controller:

```
def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end
```

The route should already be in your routes.rb file, so add this to your job `index` page:

```
<%= link_to job.position, job_path(job) %>
```

where `job` is the job you want to display.